# Подскажите как реализовать сервер для Android приложений

Tags: java, android

Я разрабатываю приложение под Android и хотел бы узнать как реализовать сервер который бы принимал данные и сохранял их в базу данных желательно в NoSQL что то вроде Mongodb. Я не ищу готовых ответов просто подскажите какие нибудь технологии либо ссылки на источники

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Присмотритесь к https://firebase.google.com/

Для тестового сервера не для продакшена очень даже хорошее решение.